# WCF REST message logging, POST request problems

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, post, logging

I got WCF REST Service and I want every message recived\sent from this service to be logged. In my app.config i got this configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>    
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>     
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="logs\\messages.svclog"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
              name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
              <filter type="" />
          </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

I`m using this binding for my service

```
 WebHttpBinding basicWebBinding = new WebHttpBinding
        {
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0),
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0),
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0),
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0),
            WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
            {
                MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,     
            }
        };
```

and this operation contract(yes, it emulates aspx page)

```
 [OperationContract(Name = "process.aspx")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
          Stream ProcessRequest(Stream data);
```

Everythig seems fine but i cant see any POST data for requests, for example

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<HttpRequest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<Connection>keep-alive</Connection>
<Content-Length>123</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</Content-Type>
<Accept>text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8</Accept>
<Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
<Accept-Language>ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3</Accept-Language>
<Host>localhost</Host>
<Referer>http://localhost/...</Referer>
<User-Agent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0</User-Agent>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<Binary xmlns=""></Binary>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

and response

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<HttpRequest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<Connection>keep-alive</Connection>
<Content-Length>159</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</Content-Type>
<Accept>*/*</Accept>
<Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
<Accept-Language>ru</Accept-Language>
<Host>localhost...</Host>
<User-Agent>agent</User-Agent>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>... stream ...</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

Any help on this would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the POST data is exceeding the default message logging length.

Have you tried adding maxSizeOfMessageToLog="200000" to the messageLogging element? (obviously you can set the size as required)

Here are settings I use successfully.

```
<messageLogging 
logEntireMessage="true" 
logMalformedMessages="false"
logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
maxMessagesToLog="3000"
maxSizeOfMessageToLog="200000"/>
```

Cheers
Chris

Comment: I think it adds an entry to the windows event log if the message size is the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting maxSizeOfMessageToLog didn`t resolve this issue, i`m still getting <Binary xmlns=""></Binary> in request, and with logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" : <MessageLogTraceRecord>... stream ...</MessageLogTraceRecord> as response

Comment: Is the stream coming through okay for you to deserialise? I presume this is coming from a form post judging by the content type?

Comment: What happens if you use the TextWriterTraceListener instead of the XML trace listener?

Comment: yes, the incoming and outcoming messages are fine,actually incoming post message looks like generic GET string (?a=1&b=4....) and no longer  than 50 characters

Comment: using TextWriterTraceListener didn`t help too,now traceViewer cant open my .svclog fiel,but if i open it with notepad i can see that messages are same as before and only file structure changed.

Comment: Might be worth using your own trace listener to see what you get. You can derive from TraceListener and override Write and WriteLine.

Comment: I really dunno why i`m getting "... stream .." entry when i explicitly set transfer mode to buffered

Comment: i`ll look into implementing custom tracer, thank you @Chris , but still it loks strange

Comment: This kind of explains it [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/a3424ba0-c50f-4d89-92f3-eaf945cd9877)

Comment: And this explains it better [link](http://www.pvle.be/2009/03/messagetostring-returning-stream/)

Comment: I read that articles before, but i thought both cases mentioned transferMode=Streamed, by the way, before using standart WCF traces i implemented custom IDispatchMessageInspector, but this method is less configurable on-the-fly